# filling missing data in array crosstab

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, missing-data, crosstab

How to aggregate data into array in such a way so as to not miss data
For example I have query for annual report of all registrated users from January to December:

```
    with s_table as (

    SELECT
     city,
     gs.mounth as month,
     coalesce(count(city),0) as count
    FROM
     generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-12-31'::date , interval '1 month') as gs(mounth)
    LEFT JOIN "user"
        ON to_char("user".datereg, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(gs.mounth::date, 'YYYY-MM')
    GROUP BY city, gs.mounth
)
    select city,
    array_agg(count) as count
    from s_table
    group by s_table.city
    order by s_table.city;
```

It returns with missing data:

```
|City  |arr_agg|
|Dublin|{1}|               //ONLY DECEMBER IS FILLED!
|Berlin|{1,4,5,10}            //ONLY JAN,MAR,APR,OCT ARE FILLED!
```

Expect result

```
    |City  |       Count users        |
    |Dublin|{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} |
    |Berlin|{1,0,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0}|
```

How to fill missing data with '0'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate all months for all cities.  To get the rows, think `cross join`:

```
with s_table as (
      select c.city, gs.month as month,
             count(u.city) as count
      from generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, '2017-12-31'::date , interval '1 month') as gs(month) cross join
           (select distinct u.city from user u) c left join
           "user" u
           on date_trunc('month', u.datereg,) = date_trunc(gs.month::date) and
              u.city = c.city
        group by c.city, gs.month
       )
select city, array_agg(count order by month) as count
from s_table
group by s_table.city
order by s_table.city;
```

Note other changes in the answer:

- The date comparisons use date functions rather than strings.
- The `array_agg()` has an `order by`.
- There is no need to convert the result of the `generate_series()` to a date.
- `count()` does not return `NULL`, so the `coalese()` is unnecessary.

Comment: are there any alternatives?